# Jumpy Menu Items

Tags: css

I'm new to css and having a problem with one of my menu items. The menu item jumps up and down when you roll over it which means there must be a pad or margin somewhere causing it. I removed different pads and margin but it still jumpy. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code if you run your mouse over Practice Area's and slowly move over "Employment Law" and "Civil Rights" you will see the menu/text jump.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/v4qnU/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the selectors, `#menu li:hover` was too greedy.  It was changing the height of the li elements causing the jumoing.  I changed it to `#menu > li:hover` and there is no jumping in that menu now.  I forked the fiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/ypJwz/

Comment: Thank you very much that was it!! i'm new to css but learning could you explain what > does to li:hover?

Comment: `>` is the child selector.  In `a > b` it selects b if it is a child, or directly beneath, a.  i.e. `.foo > .bar` would select the inner span in `<span class="foo">some text<span class="bar">some more text</span></span>`.  You can find more detailed info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: So is it kind of like !important? It tells css to use bar vs foo?

Comment: Not really.  Actually, that example I gave isn't great.  Here's a better one:
`<div class="foo"><div class="bar"><div class="baz"></div></div></div>`  `.foo .bar` would select both the bar and baz divs whils `.foo > .bar` would select only the bar div.

Comment: Okay, I don't get it but I will look up the link you provided to see if I can make sense of it. But thank you very much for your help!!